# Math Analysis. Prove $C_b$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $N$ be a normed vector space, let $M$ be a metric space, and let $A$ be a subset of $M$.  Let $V$ denote the space of all bounded functions from $A$ to $N$, with the sup norm.  Let $C_b$ denote the set of all bounded continuous functions from $A$ to $N$.  Show that $C_b$ is closed in $V$.

I think I'm suppose to use Arzela-Ascoli Theorem but do not know how to go about it

Comment: What is $C_b{}$?  What topology are you putting on the space of all bounded functions on $A$?

Comment: C={f€V| f is continuous} where V is the set of all functions f: A to N. N is a normed vector space and A € M and M is a metric space. $C_b$ is a subset of C consisting of bounded functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Arzela-Ascoli won't be helpful here.  To show that $C_b$ is closed, suppose you have a sequence $f_n$ of elements of $C_b$ which converge to some function $f\in V$.  You want to show that $f$ is in $C_b$.  To show this, you can use the fact that a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: That hint was given to me in the back of the book but that made me more confused.

Comment: I have added a bit more detail.  Are you still confused?

Comment: So since fn converges to a function f in Cb, fn is closed and therefore Cb is closed in V?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f_n$ is closed"?

Comment: Fn is closed in Cb because it converges to f and f is in Cb right?